# Get sum of data in several firebase nodes

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I'm developing an ionic 2 app.
I have this kind of data in firebase 
[image]

what i need is go throgh the **exams** node and get total of all marks.
in firebase docs there are examples like this.

```
var query = firebase.database().ref("users").orderByKey();
query.once("value")
  .then(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      // key will be "ada" the first time and "alan" the second time
      var key = childSnapshot.key;
      // childData will be the actual contents of the child
      var childData = childSnapshot.val();
  });
});
```

but i have no idea how to use this for my case.
can anyone please help me??

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this quite easily in [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4)

```
>_ npm install --save lodash
```

---

```
import { forEach,sum} from 'lodash';

...

let marks:[];
forEach(this.exam,value => {
  marks.push(value.mark);
});
console.log(sum(marks));
```

[Sum](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#sum)

Comment: Thnx for the idea.definitely need to use and check.Thnx

Answer (score 0):

Your json structure is wrong, reconfigure to achieve as below

```
exams : [ { name: '50' , marks :50 },
           { name: 'exam1' , marks :60 }

        ]
```

by this you can loop in and calculate the sum of all marks

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Here is my code to add new examno and marks.but if i going to do like your answer how to add marks separtely.It will just overwrites all other data.                                                                                                                                                                                     `Addexams(userid){ let exams={ examid:this.examno, marks:this.marks } return new Promise((reslove)=>{ this.userProfile.child(userid).set({exams}); reslove(true); }); } `    @Aravind @aravind

Comment: I didn't get you. elaborate